# How to conditionally set header and footer of pages?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab

It's my first time using reportlab to generate pdfs, it's VERY hard for me to understand how it works (it took me a day to even put a sized SVG image :D)

##### I want to achieve a very basic pdf:

As you can see in the images: 1 cover page, then 2 pages with header and footer BUT header with text is only on the first page...

Text is not static at all, it can break up to 4-5 pages, in the future there could be another section with title with different text.

Also I think what is very hard is to set text's `Frame.topPadding` to be variable based on
header height... I can't even imagine how to do this xD

[image: cover]
[image: page1]
[image: page2]

##### This is my code right now

I've achieved to do the first page, it was pretty easy, but when it came to `Frame`s, `PageTemplate`s and other, my head blew up...

```py
    def _header(self, canvas, doc, title=None):
        # Save the state of our canvas so we can draw on it
        canvas.saveState()

        y_pad = 50
        header_height = (y_pad * 2) + (self.styles['heading'].leading if text else 0)
        header_frame = Frame(
            x1=0,
            y1=self.height - header_height,
            width=self.width,
            height=header_height,
            topPadding=y_pad,
            bottomPadding=y_pad
        )

        canvas.setFillColor(DARKGRAY)
        canvas.rect(0, self.height - header_height, self.width, header_height, fill=1)
        if text:
            header_frame.addFromList([
                Paragraph(text, self.styles['heading'])
            ], canvas)

        # Release the canvas
        canvas.restoreState()

    def _dark_page(self, canvas, doc):
        canvas.saveState()

        canvas.setFillColor(DARKGRAY)
        canvas.rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height, fill=1)

        canvas.restoreState()

    def _create(self):
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate(
            self.buffer,
            topMargin=0,
            rightMargin=0,
            leftMargin=0,
            bottomMargin=0,
            pagesize=A4
        )

        story = []

        # cover page template with dark background set by self._dark_page
        main_page_template = PageTemplate(id='main', frames=[
            Frame(0, 0, self.width, self.height, 0, 100, 0, 100)
        ], onPage=self._dark_page)

        # basic page template for any further text about product
        body_page_template = PageTemplate(id='body', frames=[
            Frame(0, 0, self.width, self.height, 80, 120, 80, 120, showBoundary=1)
        ], onPage=lambda c,d: self._header(c, d, title='title title title title')

        doc.addPageTemplates([main_page_template, body_page_template])


        story.append(NextPageTemplate('main'))

        logo = svg2rlg(LOGO_PATH)
        logo.width = logo.minWidth() * 0.4
        logo.height = logo.height * 0.4
        logo.scale(0.4, 0.4)
        # logo._showBoundary = 1
        logo.hAlign = 'CENTER'
        story.append(logo)

        story.append(Spacer(width=0, height=80))
        # maybe there's a way to position the image in the center between elements,
        # like justify-content: between in css...
        image = Image(self._get_product_image_path(), 320, 320)
        story.append(image)
        story.append(Spacer(width=0, height=80))

        title = Paragraph(self.product.title, self.styles['heading'])
        story.append(title)
        if self.product.breed.name_latin:
            story += [
                Spacer(width=0, height=10),
                Paragraph(self.product.breed.name_latin, self.styles['subheading'])
            ]


        story.append(NextPageTemplate('body'))
        story.append(PageBreak())

        # actual text
        story.append(Paragraph(text*4, self.styles['body']))

        doc.build(story)
```

##### So the question is

How do I set header and footer on the page, and if page breaks, next page with same header and footer, but header without title until the last page of the `PageTemplate`?

I've tried to get page numbers in `self._header` `doc` argument, but it's returning the first page number of the `PageTemplate`, not every page, maybe there's a way to get a page number from 0(first page used by some template) to the last page used by this template?

**THANKS in advance!** It already took me 3 days to try to achieve this...